# Cloud Run deploying via YAML says Image not found

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-artifact-registry

I have two Cloud Run Knative YAML files for staging and production. I have two GCP projects for staging and production and two sets of Artifact Registry.

I use the simple zip and build like this:

```sh
gcloud builds submit --tag us-east1-docker.pkg.dev/proj-a/repo-x/image-y:1.0
```

I then edit the `yaml` to adjust the tag at the end and then redeploy with:

```sh
gcloud run services replace staging.yaml
```

This was all working the other day and my staging and production sites are up. It also just worked for my production project a moment ago.

I just switched project using `gcloud config set core/project proj-b` and then ran these two commands again, making the necessary adjustments.

The first command succeeded; the image was built and I can see it in Artifact Registry.

But the second command failed with:

> Applying new configuration to Cloud Run service [cloud-run-z] in project [01234567890] region [us-east1]
>
> X Deploying... Image 'us-east1-docker.pkg.dev/proj-a/repo-x/image-y:1.0' not found.
>
> X Creating Revision... Image 'us-east1-docker.pkg.dev/proj-a/repo-x/image-y:1.0' not found.
>
> . Routing traffic...
>
> Deployment failed
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.run.services.replace) Image 'us-east1-docker.pkg.dev/proj-a/repo-x/image-y:1.0' not found.

I can see the image, I've pasted its URL as written in the console into my `yaml` to be sure, and this was working the other day.

Why can't Cloud Run see the image that I can see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was typing this question I remembered the only difference I'd introduced between the two projects: I had configured production to run as a user-managed service account. I had done this in order to allow it to access production secrets (that staging does not use).

So I added a new service account to my staging project and gave it the Secret Manager Secret Accessor role, then configured via YAML to run as this account, then redeployed and it worked.

This doesn't actually make any sense to me. It seems to a) have nothing to do with Artifact Registry b) explain why it was working the other day.